# Warning: Unexpected block "content"

Tags: pug, pugjs

Even though I've got the blocks correctly addressed they aren't being brought into the layout page:

```
//- layout.jade
doctype html
html
  head
      title My Page
  body
    block content //- Main content goes here




//- index.jade
extends ./layout.jade

block title
  title Article Title

block content
  h1 My Article
```

I've since found the answer and think it should be documented to help others...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get that error if you have a comment `//-` on the same line as the block in your layout.jade.