# Pug : unexpected_block Error

Tags: html, gulp, pug

**Hi All**

I faced this error

> PUG:UNEXPECTED_BLOCK

Pug Version : **5.6.0**

Used **Gulp** for compiling

**template.pug**

```
//- Vars
- var siteName = "LandingPage" ;

block Vars

doctype html
html(lang="en")
    include head.pug
    body
        include header
        block content
        include footer
        include modals
        include scripts
```

**index.pug**

```
extends template/template

//- Vars
block vars
    - var pageTitle=" Home "; 
    - var pageDes="HTML App Landing Page Template";

//- Content
block content
    main
        include sections/content_section
```

Any Help ?

**Note :**   I tried to

- **Remove** the **block vars** that at template.pug but still gives me same error
- **Remove** all comments form both according to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36325908/4015523) but same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue .
The issue with the **block names**.

At **template.pug**, It was named the block vars with **capitalize ** ( Vars )

```
block Vars
```

and at **index.pug** It was named with **lowercase** ( vars )

```
block vars
```

I fixed the block name at it works.

Hope this help

Thanks